# Why isnt table background showing?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have  a table which I'm trying to apply a background image but it doesn't show. The image path is right ( firebug says image loaded) and the table size is same as image size (156X46px)

HTML:

```
<!--hazard icons start here -->
                <table class="hazard-table">
                <tr> 
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> 1 </td>

                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> 1 </td>

                </tr>


                <!-- hazard icons end here -->
                </table>
```

CSS:

```
table.hazard-table {
    background:url('../images/icon-item.png') no-repeat;
    width:156px;
    height:46px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#ebebeb;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
}
table.hazard-table th {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: #ebebeb;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: ;
}
table.hazard-table td {
    background-position:30 20 ;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: #ebebeb;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table.hazard-table {
    background:url('../images/icon-item.png') no-repeat;
    width:156px;
    height:46px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#ebebeb;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
}
```

This :

```
background-color: white;
```

override the image with a background of white.
You should do instead :

```
  table.hazard-table {
        background:white url('../images/icon-item.png') no-repeat;
        width:156px;
        height:46px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-spacing: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color:#ebebeb;
        border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

**EDIT :**

try this :

```
  table{
.hazard-table {
    background:white url("../images/icon-item.png") no-repeat;
    width:156px;
    height:46px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#ebebeb;
    border-collapse: collapse;


    th{
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 1px;
        border-style: inset;
        border-color: #ebebeb;
        background-color: white;
        -moz-border-radius: ;
        } 

        td{
           background-position:30 20 ;
           border-width: 1px;
           padding: 1px;
           border-style: inset;
           border-color: #ebebeb;
           background-color: white;
           -moz-border-radius: ;
       }
}
```

Comment: Woops. I completely missed that background-color:white; Nice job :)

Comment: try [`code`]background-image:url('../images/icon-item.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-color:#fff;[`code`]

Comment: Oh sorry it works! Thanks a lot! Forgot that I had applied background-color to <tr> <td> too.

Answer (score 1):

```
}
table.hazard-table td {
    background-position:30 20 ;
```

As a starter, the background-position must be pixels, or "center" etc.

```
}
table.hazard-table td {
    background-position:30px 20px ;
```

This "might" fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVuS6/13/)** link will work for you .

```
  table.hazard-table {
   /* background:url('../images/icon-item.png') no-repeat 0 0;*/
    background:url('http://img.talkandroid.com/uploads/2013/03/wpid-photo-jan-14-2013-1115-am.jpg') no-repeat 0 -550px;
    width:156px;
    height:46px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#ebebeb;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    /* background-color: white;*/
}
table.hazard-table th {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: #ebebeb;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: ;
}
table.hazard-table td {
    background-position:30 20 ;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: #ebebeb;
   /* background-color: white;*/
    -moz-border-radius: ;
}
```